# Stop loading data from url

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

How do I interrupt asynchronous loading when the view disappears?

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

I don't want the data to be overwritten if the user popped the view controller (and because of the slow connection it's still downloading data). Should I use Alamofire or there's any way to do it here?

Comment: Where is `data` stored?

Comment: If you are using an url session you can `invalidateAndCancel()` it.

Comment: try data.write(to: localAudioUrl) I'm downloading a mp3 file and storing it locally. Should I use dataTask instead? Just noticed

Comment: Kowboj, I recommend you to use URLSession's download task because you are downloading a file.

Comment: Thank you @Desdenova, invalidating works perfect.